# How can I read 3 csv files and display them in order in the console? (JAVA)

Tags: java, csv, object

I need to read 3 csv files in java.
So this part I've managed but I'd like to optimise my code for the next part.

I'd like to be able to sort in the same way as in the Excel file in the console.

In fact my final objective is to take the first file, check the questions in it to see if they exist. Then, once I've chosen the question, I'll have 2 files that look the same, so I'll have to compare them and see if there are any discrepancies.

That's why I'd like to know how to sort at the start.

Thanks in advance.

```
package readAndPrint;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class read3file {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Définir les fichiers et leur emplacements
        String sPathDirectory ="C:\\Users\\...\\Downloads\\";
        String pathFileQR = sPathDirectory + "QR.csv";
        String pathFilePivot = sPathDirectory + "PivotSegmentQuestion.csv";
        String pathFileNCL = sPathDirectory + "PivotSegmentQuestionNCL.csv";
        
        
        //Lire et afficher QR.csv
        readAndPrintFile(pathFileQR);
        
        //Lire et afficher PivotSegmentQuestion.csv
        readAndPrintFile(pathFilePivot);
        
        //Lire et afficher PivotSegmentQuestionNCL.csv
        readAndPrintFile(pathFileNCL);
        }
    
        //Methode pour lire les fichiers et les afficher
        private static void readAndPrintFile(String filePath) {
            String line = "";
            
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
                while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null)
                    System.out.println(line);
                
                System.out.println("Fichier trouvé: " + filePath); //Confirmation 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Fichier introuvable :" + filePath); //Affichage message erreur
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: *I'd like to be able to sort in the same way as in the Excel file in the console.* Presumably, you mean by a given field, or fields? If you're going to do that, you need to tokenize each line. I'd advise, since the file contains *questions*, that you don't use a comma as a delimiter as that would make it hard for a question to contain a comma, *unless you use a proper csv api*

Comment: @g00se I would just advise using a proper csv api to begin with.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, probably better to do so. I'm just erring on the side of what I imagine is *likely to happen* ;)

Comment: Explain "sort in the same way as in the Excel file in the console". What Excel file? What does "sort in same way" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadCSVFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Specify the paths to your CSV files
        String[] filePaths = {"file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"};

        try {
            // Loop through each file
            for (String filePath : filePaths) {
                System.out.println("Reading file: " + filePath);
                readAndDisplayCSV(filePath);
                System.out.println(); // Add a newline between files
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void readAndDisplayCSV(String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Split the CSV values and display them
                String[] values = line.split(",");
                for (String value : values) {
                    System.out.print(value + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println(); // Move to the next line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the CSV file contains `Actor,"Sammy Davis, Jr.",1925-12-08` what is your `line.split(",")` going to end up with? You should use a CSV library like Apache Commons CSV to read and write CSV files.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the OP's question isnt it?

Comment: It is a general concern whenever reading CSV files. OP didn't give any indication of what is in the CSV files. They might contain embedded commas, they might not. We have no way of knowing.

Comment: *We have no way of knowing.* Though we can say that placing the restriction that the input *can't* contain commas is not only not practical, but also wholly unnecessary if things are handled in the right way

Comment: I got the answer to my question. Thank you all for your help !